# SMD capacitor selection

Tags: capacitor, circuit-analysis, circuit-design, power-electronics, surface-mount

I'm trying to purchase SMD capacitors online, but I'm not sure how to identify the voltage rating of the SMD capacitor.

- How can we calculate the voltage rating of an SMD ceramic capacitor?
- Is it dependent on the package size or what are factors to be considered?

Comment: Set a filter to only display capacitors for the voltage you want and above.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There's nothing to "identify" or "calculate". You buy a capacitor whose product page clearly states the voltage rating. (and, no, you can't infer voltage rating from anything like package size. It's simply a property that the manufacturer of the capacitor designed and priced into their capacitor, and many capacitors that look *exactly* the same exist with very different ratings.)

An electronics seller who doesn't offer that crucial information on their website is essentially a scam, or really really bad at their job. Pick a different seller; the reputable ones include digikey, farnell/newark/element14/element14 APAC (same company, essentially), mouser, arrow, but there's others, too. octopart is a classical way to find sellers of electronic components, but many will not sell you less than a couple thousand capacitors at once, so look out for the MOQ (minimum order quantity).

Answer (score 11):

Marcus has it almost correct.

You don't calculate the voltage of a capacitor, you read it from the specifications. Any supplier worth dealing with will present you with the voltage information.

However, with ceramic capacitors, especially high capacitance small package ones, you have to interpret what the voltage means for the capacitance.

If you buy a high capacitance ceramic that's rated (say) 6.3 V 4.7 uF, then you will be able to apply 6.3 V without it breaking. However, you may find that at 6.3 V its capacitance had dropped to much less than 2 uF, once you've taken tolerance, temperature coefficient and voltage coefficient into account. This is important if it's being used to stabilise a voltage regulator, or hold up a circuit during a brownout.

The problem is that modern high-K ceramics have a fierce voltage coefficient of capacitance, and that designations like Y5U **do not** code for the voltco, only for the tempco. In order to find out what the voltco of a particular capacitor ceramic is, you **may well have to take the package size into account**, as you comb through the manufacturer's data sheets, because they may use a different dielectric if they choose to offer the same capacitance and voltage rating in a smaller size package. Often data sheets with sufficient information are not easily available, even on the manufacturer's website, and you may have to ask them directly. Once you've characterised a particular brand, voltage, capacitance and package size, you'll need to ensure you can always source that particular one.

This problem only occurs with high-K ceramics. Electrolytics, film capacitors, and low-K ceramics like NP0 have a negligible voltage coefficient. Older high-K dielectrics like X7R have a voltco in the several percent, which is not negligible, but is not as surprising and fierce as the newer high-K's.

The workaround for high-K ceramics to make sure you have enough capacitance is to use the capacitor at less than half its rated voltage, or to specify several times the capacitance you really need. If you want a close tolerance value, then you should not be using ceramics.

Comment: You're right even major manufacturers don't put much data in the datasheet, but there's usually a quicker way to get the data besides asking them directly, assuming that means sending someone an email and waiting for a response. For example, Kemet has [K-SIM](https://ksim3.kemet.com/) and muRata has [SimSurfing](https://www.murata.com/en-us/tool).

Comment: @PhilFrost Those links look as if they could be useful. Do they go as far as capacitance versus voltage, for specific part numbers?

Comment: Yes they do. They also have parasitic parameters.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to what Marcus and Neil said in their absolutely correct answers, I just wanted to add something about the size:

> Is it dependent on the package size or what are factors to be considered?

Normally you can't even estimate the voltage rating by only using the physical dimensions. But, low-capacitance capacitors *(e.g. <100nF)* with higher voltage ratings *(e.g. >100V)* tend to be in larger packages like 1206, 1210, 2010, etc for safety reasons *(i.e. to meet the required creepage/clearance distances)*.

Answer (score 2):

To elaborate on the points above about package size and voltage:

https://ds.murata.co.jp/simsurfing/mlcc.html?lcid=en-us

Above is a parametric search tool that lets you specify the voltage you are using and search for a part that will have the capacitance you need at that specific voltage. You can see that generally package size gets larger as effective capacitance goes up at higher voltages, but also within a package size different models are more or less impacted by voltage. In a lot of applications this is very important to consider because the effective capacitance can vary widely even when two capacitors have the exact same nominal capacitance. Picking the right part can save you a lot of headache later.