# What type of polarized surface mount capacitor should I use?

Tags: capacitor, surface-mount

I am having a PCB printed by OSH Park and then I will hand-solder surface mount components onto it. For my design, I am using two polarized capacitors; one is the timing capacitor for a 555 timer and the other "slowly" charges and discharges to create a changing reference voltage for a part of the circuit. Both caps will be 4.7uF.

In the past I have used 1206 nonpolarized capacitors for these functions and they seemed to work without a problem. However, for this new design I have some questions:

1. Should I be using polarized capacitors for these functions mentioned above? I don't believe there is any reason I need to.
2. If I get polarized capacitors, I think I will get 1206 or 0805 tantalum capacitors from Mouser as they are a convenient physical size and price. I'd like to spend less than $1 per cap. Would these caps be a good choice/is there any reason not to use them?

Comment: You might want to take [SMD capacitor selection](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/536218/36731) into consideration with regard to the voltage rating.

Comment: The critical factor in time delays > 1s is the cap leakage specs for RpC product. that limits the maximum discharge time.  Not all e-caps can do this and they leak more with higher temps. and also V rating dependent on capacitance so choose much higher V ratings

Comment: Why do you consider using polarized capacitors? I'd just use ordinary ceramic caps, 4.7uF in 1206 is not very special and shouldn't even cost $1.

Comment: Do you understand why 99% of your information is irrelevant with "timing" and "slowly" "size" and <1$. Where are all your specs and tolerances for everything that matters for input options, and all functions, appearance, performance and cost, and purpose?. Make a concise list of specs and tolerances ( if it is a "must-have" or "nice to have" or optional). then you will learn an important 1st  step to design.  Chosing parts is not the 1st step

Comment: @AndrewMorton Yes I see in the other reading about how various capacitors may not always meet an advertised voltage rating. Traditionally, I choose a voltage rating higher than what I need. Also I see how the timing information is not relevant (I just included it to generally imply I'm not working with something like RF); it seems tolerance of capacitance value is most important. In this case, I can afford 20% tolerance.